# What managed switch to buy that has routing and network bandwidth monitoring capability?

Tags: router, switch

We are a small team where we have a internet lease line of 50Mbps from our office space provider (they won't allow other internet providers). We have one Ethernet cable coming from them which is plugged in our `TP-Link AC1750` router which further creates a LAN and a wifi network.

We have frequent internet disconnection issues and would like to diagnose this problem, someone suggested us to switch to a managed switch (as i was able to read the ones with routing capability are L3 switches ??).

We would like to have a device which can provide me following details:

1. How much total bandwidth of the allocated 50Mbps (WAN) are we using at any given moment and is it falling short (so we can upgrade). Also historical data of it.
2. Which system is our office is using the most internet (WAN) data (some kind of history of it)
3. If we are not choking our bandwidth and still internet is disconnecting, why is that and some kind of historical proof for it so i can show it to our internet provider.

Note: we want to know details regarding the internet data/bandwidth used and not the details of data transfer between our systems using Ethernet/Wifi on internal LAN.

This list is non-exhaustive. If there is any device which can provide these details and some extra things we are ready to buy it.

Comment: I am partial to D-Link switches because they are economical.  I would email this kind of thing to D-Link, or Cisco, and confirm they sell such a product that meets your needs.  I'm not a network guy so L2 vs L3 and diagnostic stuff i can't help you with, but i'm sure any of the major switch/router providers like them or netgear or tplink can answer your question.  just email their support email listed on their web page